# How to create a query to exclude specific obejct in table

Tags: sql

I want to ask how to create a query to exclude specific obejct in table.

I have disk table and it looks like below.

select * from disk_table

```
MACHINE    INSTANCE    METRIC

A             C:          20

B             C:          30

B             E:          40
```

I want to bring all INSTANCE except C: in B server.

how can I create a query for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a822dc/4/0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM disk_table 
WHERE NOT (Machine = 'B' AND Instance = 'C:')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I query like this, A server does not in the list. I want to show all servers and exclude C: in B server. how can I make it ?

Comment: That is because you said, **"INSTANCE except C: in B server"**, which to me means you want all records with `Machine` of `B` and **NOT** an `Instance` of `C:`.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: **@이상봉**, I think I know what you are after now.  I updated my answer.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry Maybe I'm wrong, I want to show A, B server in result. so query result should be "A C: 20, B E: 40". I want to exclude only C: in B server.

Comment: **@이상봉**, fixed it, check again.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works. I just modified like this "WHERE NOT (Machine = 'B' AND Instance = 'C:')"

Answer (score 0):

just use AND operation on your condition.(all INSTANCE except C: in B server.)

```
select * from disk_table
WHERE INSTANCE <>'C:' AND MACHINE <> 'B'
```